# Is there way to change the consonant in a string with 11th consonant from consonant list?

Tags: python, encryption

List of consonant: "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
So when "z" comes in input we have to replace it with 11th element in list i.e."n"
Input: zeo
Output: nEO

I'm struggling with making the iterating over list element when the index value hits the last element of list.

My code for the reference:

```
def Encryption(s):
    encstr=""
    for i in s:
        if(i in vowels):
            encstr=encstr+i.upper()
        elif(i in consonants):
            temp = consonants.index(i)
            encstr=encstr+consonants[temp + 10]
        else:
            encstr=encstr + i
    return encstr
    
def Decryption(k):
    decstr=""
    for i in k:
        if(i in VOWELS):
            decstr=decstr+i.lower()
        elif(i in consonants):
            temp = consonants.index(i)
            decstr=decstr+consonants[temp + 10]
        else:
            decstr=decstr+i
    return decstr
    
#List Of Vowels
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
VOWELS = [vowel.upper() for vowel in vowels]

#List Of Consonants
consonants = list("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz")
CONSONANTS = [cons.upper() for cons in consonants]

print("Enter the string to Encrypt and decrypt : ")
s=input()
t=Encryption(s)
print(s)
print(t)
print(Decryption(t))
```

Comment: Do you want to only replace 'z' ?

Comment: Actually here vowels are just getting replaced by the uppercase of itself.
Yes I want to print the input string, encrypted string and decrypted string as well.
For Example: INP: ze, ENCRYPT: nE, DECRYPT: ze